# Facebook scenario - is this possible?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-c#-sdk

I'd like to know if the following is possible using Facebook apps:

I'm using the Facebook SDK for .NET and want to create an app that a page will use. The app will take a photograph from a user who happens to visit the page, that photograph should then be sent to one of the page's photo albums.

I've managed to perform this successfully, but only when logged in as the page admin. If I log out of the page admin, log in as my personal Facebook account (as most users of the app will do) then the photograph never gets sent to the pages photo album.

I would like to do all of this when the user uploads the photo, but if it isn't possible I'll need to look into a separate process to actually send the photo's to Facebook, and just store the image on my server until the process runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin photo album (aka page photo album) is not the same album as non-page admins get to upload to (which is the wall).  They are separate buckets all together.

As you mentioned, you can always just upload and store the photos on your server, and then just have a feed item that links over to that image.